# Removing special characters from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to remove all the \r\n from the python dictionary. What is the easiest way to do so. My dictionary is looking like this at the moment -

```
 {'': '34.8\r\n', 
  'Mozzarella di Giovanni\r\n': '34.8\r\n', 
   'Queso Cabrales\r\n': '14\r\n', 
   'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee\r\n': '9.8\r\n'
}
```

**EDIT** : Here's what I'm trying -

```
for key, values in productDictionary.items() :
    key.strip()
    values.strip()
    key.strip('"\"r')
    key.strip('\\n')
    values.strip('\\r\\n')
print productDictionary
```

And the output is still the same.

Comment: In your code you're actually iterating over a list(`.items()`), modifying the variables retrieved from this list doesn't affect the `dict`.

Comment: Strip returns a string that has had those characters removed, it doesn't modify the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `str.strip()`:

`str.strip()` when used with no arguments, strips all types of leading and trailing whitespaces.

```
>>> productDictionary={'': '34.8\r\n', 
  'Mozzarella di Giovanni\r\n': '34.8\r\n', 
   'Queso Cabrales\r\n': '14\r\n', 
   'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee\r\n': '9.8\r\n'
}

>>> productDictionary=dict(map(str.strip,x) for x in productDictionary.items()) 
>>> print productDictionary
>>>
{'': '34.8',
 'Mozzarella di Giovanni': '34.8',
 'Queso Cabrales': '14',
 'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee': '9.8'}
```

`help()` on `str.strip()`

> S.strip([chars]) -> string or unicode
>
> Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing whitespace
>   removed. If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars
>   instead. If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before
>   stripping

Comment: @AshishAgarwal what you're doing is incorrect, my code works fine.

Answer (score 9):

Using a dictionary comprehension:

```
clean_dict = {key.strip(): item.strip() for key, item in my_dict.items()}
```

The `strip()` function removes newlines, spaces, and tabs from the front and back of a string.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Whoops, I fixed it. It needed a colon between the key and the item, not a comma.