# Remove special characters from all hierarchical levels in a dict - Python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I have a python dict like this:

```
{
"stationlist": {
    "tunein": {
        "@base-m3u": "/sbin/tunein-station.m3u",
        "@base": "/sbin/tunein-station.pls",
        "@base-xspf": "/sbin/tunein-station.xspf"
    },
    "station": [
        {
            "@lc": "34753",
            "@br": "128",
            "@mt": "audio/mpeg",
            "@name": "Dance Wave Retro!",
            "@id": "1057402",
            "@genre": "Urban Contemporary"
        },
        {
            "@lc": "12847",
            "@br": "64",
            "@logo": "http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/a/a265/a2654f5f-669e-4b9e-ac13-962971886ad2.jpg",
            "@mt": "audio/aacp",
            "@name": "COOLfahrenheit 93 - (7)",
            "@id": "1735956",
            "@ct": "25 Hours - #11D8'1 (Soft Version)",
            "@genre": "Easy Listening",
            "@genre2": "Pop"
        },
        ...
        ...
```

I need to remove @ symbol from all the keys in the dict on all hierarchical levels.

Tried this : [Removing special characters from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366332/removing-special-characters-from-dictionary)

```
productDictionary=dict(map(str.strip,x) for x in productDictionary.items())
```

Did not help much. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examplehttps://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: did you tried `if key.startswith('@'): key = key[1:]` ?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I realize this is a good way to do it but I need to go down to all the levels in the dictionary and since this is a response from a RESTful service, I cannot know how many nests I'll be needing beforehand.. I'm looking for a way to get rid of @ in all keys in the dict irrespective of the hierarchy it is situated at. I hope you get my point :)

Comment: @WaqasHamid  out of the 3 people that down voted you, i was not one of them.. I merely provided a stock comment about keeping the code in the question as per the guidelines from the site that you are posting on.. guidelines that i did not write but I do respect.. guidelines which are there to help people find a solution.

Comment: Which I'm pretty sure, I stuck to while asking the question. The question does not show lack of effort or research. People here need to understand that it takes a lot of effort to build up a certain reputation and that we're here to help out each other rather than discouraging them by blindly giving a -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def filter_dict(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key.startswith('@'): 
            key = key[1:]
            del d["@"+key]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d[key] = filter_dict(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            d[key] = [filter_dict(l) for l in value]
        else:
            d[key]=value
    return d
```

Pass your dictionary to this function and it will produce the desired output, irrespective of the hierarchy.If `abc` is your dictionary then `filter_dict(abc)` will update abc with desired format. Note that abc will be updated automatically since dictionary is mutable.

**Sample code**

```
from pprint import pprint

abc = {
    "stationlist": {
        "tunein": {
            "@base-m3u": "/sbin/tunein-station.m3u",
            "@base": "/sbin/tunein-station.pls",
            "@base-xspf": "/sbin/tunein-station.xspf"
        },
        "station": [
            {
                "@lc": "34753",
                "@br": "128",
                "@mt": "audio/mpeg",
                "@name": "Dance Wave Retro!",
                "@id": "1057402",
                "@genre": "Urban Contemporary"
            },
            {
                "@lc": "12847",
                "@br": "64",
                "@logo": "http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/a/a265/a2654f5f-669e-4b9e-ac13-962971886ad2.jpg",
                "@mt": "audio/aacp",
                "@name": "COOLfahrenheit 93 - (7)",
                "@id": "1735956",
                "@ct": "25 Hours - #11D8'1 (Soft Version)",
                "@genre": "Easy Listening",
                "@genre2": "Pop"
            },
        ]
     }
 }

def filter_dict(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key.startswith('@'): 
            key = key[1:]
            del d["@"+key]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d[key] = filter_dict(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            d[key] = [filter_dict(l) for l in value]
        else:
            d[key]=value
    return d


print "before"
pprint(abc)

filter_dict(abc)

print "after"
pprint(abc)
```

**Output**

```
before
{'stationlist': {'station': [{'@br': '128',
                              '@genre': 'Urban Contemporary',
                              '@id': '1057402',
                              '@lc': '34753',
                              '@mt': 'audio/mpeg',
                              '@name': 'Dance Wave Retro!'},
                             {'@br': '64',
                              '@ct': "25 Hours - #11D8'1 (Soft Version)",
                              '@genre': 'Easy Listening',
                              '@genre2': 'Pop',
                              '@id': '1735956',
                              '@lc': '12847',
                              '@logo': 'http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/a/a265/a2654f5f-669e-4b9e-ac13-962971886ad2.jpg',
                              '@mt': 'audio/aacp',
                              '@name': 'COOLfahrenheit 93 - (7)'}],
                 'tunein': {'@base': '/sbin/tunein-station.pls',
                            '@base-m3u': '/sbin/tunein-station.m3u',
                            '@base-xspf': '/sbin/tunein-station.xspf'}}}

after
{'stationlist': {'station': [{'br': '128',
                              'genre': 'Urban Contemporary',
                              'id': '1057402',
                              'lc': '34753',
                              'mt': 'audio/mpeg',
                              'name': 'Dance Wave Retro!'},
                             {'br': '64',
                              'ct': "25 Hours - #11D8'1 (Soft Version)",
                              'genre': 'Easy Listening',
                              'genre2': 'Pop',
                              'id': '1735956',
                              'lc': '12847',
                              'logo': 'http://i.radionomy.com/document/radios/a/a265/a2654f5f-669e-4b9e-ac13-962971886ad2.jpg',
                              'mt': 'audio/aacp',
                              'name': 'COOLfahrenheit 93 - (7)'}],
                 'tunein': {'base': '/sbin/tunein-station.pls',
                            'base-m3u': '/sbin/tunein-station.m3u',
                            'base-xspf': '/sbin/tunein-station.xspf'}}}
```

Comment: I will surely try this and get back to you in a bit.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/beginner007/7a987c217ed6cb81d2a2c2f09d15d184  I still have some @ left.

Comment: Processed your request,but i haven't seen any @ in the result

Comment: This is what I get : https://gist.github.com/beginner007/6bf7a4c00693067ff580bd4ad4da7e50

Comment: So thats the result. can you send me the the data before processing

Comment: Here you go : https://gist.github.com/beginner007/069601f37ed93b04dfca42f74ff31a70

Comment: this is the result i m getting : https://github.com/AneeshRS/testrepo/blob/master/result.txt

Comment: Ok. Then there is something wrong with the way I am using it. Are you sure you're using the above snippet. Can you please check once, if you've modified it?

Comment: I'm packing the dict in a Response() to return to a RESTful endpoint. Could Response() be creating a problem here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166394/discussion-between-aneesh-rs-and-waqas-hamid).